# PHP Advanced RegEX on URLs

Tags: php, regex

I have a large list which is populated with different types of feed urls for cameras, the URL structure is slightly different each time.

I need to strip out or replace the Segments/fields from the different URL types and create valid ones, I am not sure if this is even possible with regular expressions

Examples of URLS:

```
rtsp://IPADDRESS/
http://IPADDRESS/videostream.asf
http://IPADDRESS//iphone/11?[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]&
http://IPADDRESS/img/video.mjpeg
```

Segments which always exist:
IPADDRESS

Segments which are always the same (if they exist)
IPADDRESS
[USERNAME]
[PASSSWORD]

The end results is I need to separate each segment into variables so I can use them to create a valid URL.

For example I will use this URL "http://IPADDRESS//iphone/11?[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]" and replace the segments with valid data

EDIT:

The URLS are stored in a database, its not coming from the URL field in a browser.

I am attempting it using multiple str_replaces, but I am not sure how reliable this is, it might be better with a loop. But how would you break the url up using a loop:

```
$string = str_replace('IPADDRESS', '10.10.10.10', $string);
$string = str_replace('[USERNAME]', 'user1', $string);

http://10.10.10.10//iphone/11?user1:mypass
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: Two things to remember: 1) Regexes are not a magic wand that you wave at any problem that happens to involve strings.  2) Common tasks like handling URL contents usually have existing functions to take care of them.

Comment: 3) Those existing functions often use regexes, so... maybe they are a magic wand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're actually looking for [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url).

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.

Comment: Thats very helpful, thanks I am looking into this now